# How to NOT wait for exit using Impersonataion.RunProcess In c#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, impersonation, privileges

What I want to know is if there is a way to NOT wait for a process when using impersonation. There's no overloads so I'm not sure how to do this.

```
// always waits for exit to continue
Impersonation.RunProcess(someProcessPath);
```

The reason I want to do this is that I have a long executing application that processes large files, but I want to deliver a success response to the client that the process has began before directing them to a status page. I cannot run the process with a normal process.Start() because the IUSER needs to impersonate an elevated user account.

I've even tried using process.StartInfo after Impersonation.Login() and supplying a un/pass, but I think the "logged in" status is part of the static Impersonation class only.

```
if (Impersonation.Logon(LoginCredentials.UserName, LoginCredentials.Password))
{
                // this fails with an invalid privileges exit code
                process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";                    
                SecureString secString  = new SecureString();
                foreach( char c in "mypassword" )
                    secString.AppendChar( c );
                process.StartInfo.Password = secString;
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.Start();
 }
```

I've found a zillion posts on how to wait for a normally invoked process to end before continuing using Process.WaitForExit(). I've also successfully ignored the exit by using process.start() by itself inside console apps (already authenticated).

Comment: After trying about everything to find a graceful .NET solution, my workaround is to just do two ajax calls on the frontend. One call to save/confirm the data, and another call to a service that just invokes the process, one where the browser just ignores the response and lets it timeout.

Comment: wouldn't it have been easier to grant IUSER the necessary privileges instead of impersonation? there you would e.g. also be able to restricts the rights to the folder you want or readonly access and so on on Filesystem level.

Comment: Even with the ISUSRS account, the process still takes a long time to exit on the thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could fork it of to a different thread:

```
// using ThreadPool for long running tasks is discouraged so create a new thread
var t = new Thread(() => Impersonation.RunProcess(someProcessPath)) { IsBackground = true };
t.Start();
```

You could set some flags inside the thread method to indicate when it was called and when it has finished.

Comment: This seems to launch the app (I can see it in taskman) but the "I'm alive" stamp in the log file never shows, the app never exits and performs no tasks. Again, I can manually launch it just fine... It does allow the web request to complete however.

Answer (score 0):

```
Impersonation.RunProcess("/path/to/cmd.exe /C start "+someProcessPath);
```

This will return when cmd.exe ends, which is after **starting** someProcessPath

Comment: This still does not seem to pass the authenticated credentials, it bails right away (I have my someProcess writing to a log file on the first line so I know if it has run). I also confirmed by going on the server and using cmd to run the path manually and it launches as expected.